# C# Windows Forms - link instances of same Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like to create, say 32 Windows Forms based upon a single template Form, and those instances should be linked to each other. That is, every Form has a button for calling the next instance and so on. I am able to create as many forms as I like but how would I link those instances together ?

This is what I use to create several child forms:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm child = new ChildForm();
        child.Show();
    }
}
```

Sequence of events would be like:

- User starts application, main form is displayed (only has "Open Child" button)
- User pushes "Open child" button, first instance of child form opens
- first child form (caption "Child Form 1") has button "Open Child Form 2"
- if user pushes "Open Child Form 2" child form 1 is hidden and child form 2 is displayed
- if the last child form is reached wrap-around to child form 1

Any ideas are welcome !

regards

Chris

Comment: Use a constructor parameter.

Comment: You can create a static collection of the form, in the constructor add the form instance to the list (and remove it during dispose). To figure out the next form, you can find the index of the current form and grab the next form in the list based on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a static collection of the form, in the constructor add the form instance to the list (and remove it during dispose). To figure out the next form, you can find the index of the current form and grab the next form in the list based on that. Create a form with two buttons and modify it as below to test it out.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static List<Form1> formList = new List<Form1>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            formList.Add(this);
        }



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int idx = formList.IndexOf(this);
            int nextIdx = (idx == formList.Count()-1 ?  0: idx+1 );

            Form1 nextForm = formList[nextIdx];
            nextForm.changeTextAndFocus("next form: " + nextIdx);
        }

        // moves to the next form and changes the text
        public void changeTextAndFocus(string txt)
        {
            this.Focus();
            this.Text = txt;
        }

        //Creates 5 forms
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Form1 newForm = new Form1();
                newForm.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I will look into collections as well as SLaks' constructor approach (props to pinkfloyd and SLaks).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you are planning to do :). If you want to count several forms, you can add a property Number to the form. And searching upwards from there.

Mainform;

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         ChildForm first = new ChildForm();
         first.Number = 1;
         first.Show();
     }
}
```

ChildForm

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public ChildForm()
    {
        // createButton here
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm _childForm = new ChildForm();
        _childForm.Owner = this;
        _childForm.Number = this.Number + 1;
        this.Hide();
        _childForm.Show();
    }

    public void FirstChildForm()
    {
        if (this.Number != 1) //maybe not that static
        {
            (this.Owner as ChildForm).FirstChildForm();
            this.Close(); // or hide or whatever
        }
    }
    public int Number
    { get; set; }
}
```

Not tested code, hope this helps a bit :).